# Every graph of treewidth at most w can be colored with w + 1 colors

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

How can I prove that any graph of treewidth $w$ can be vertex colored with $w+1$ colors?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be our graph. If $G$ has treewidth $w$, it has a tree decomposition $T$, with vertex set $\{X_1, X_2, \dots, X_k\}$. The "vertices" of $T$ are subsets of $V$ such that every set $X_i$ has at most $w+1$ vertices (i.e, the width of $T$ is at most $w$).

We colour the vertices of $G$ as follows (the pictures show a tree decomposition of a graph with treewidth $2$).

**Step 1:** Give each vertex of $X_1$ its own colour (we have used at most $w+1$ colours so far).

[image]

**Step 2:** Now consider all the sets $X_j$ that are adjacent to $X_1$ in $T$.
Each $X_j$ has some vertices in common with $X_1$, which are already coloured. If $v$ is a vertex of $X_j-X_1$, then it is not adjacent to any vertex if $X_1-X_j$, since $T$ is a tree decomposition (basically, in $X_j$, if $v$ is not yet coloured, we can give it *any* colour we like that does not appear on another vertex of $X_j$). Thus there is at least one of the first $w+1$ colours that we can give to $v$. Going one by one through the neighbors of $X_1$, we can colour all their vertices in this way.

[image]

**Step 3:** We now look at the sets distance $2$ from $X_1$ in the tree $T$. We do the same thing as in step 1, colouring the vertices that are not yet coloured with whatever colours are left over for them.

[image]

Repeat this process until all vertices are coloured, giving $G$ a $w+1$ colouring and completing the proof.

---

You can also use the fact that the treewidth is the clique number $\omega$ of a chordal completion of $G$ minus $1$, and the fact that chordal graphs are perfect (so $\omega = \chi$), to give a one line proof (that requires knowing two big theorems).

Comment: I like your diagrams :)

Comment: Thanks, appreciated ^^

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks for the visual graphs. Made it really easy to understand!